# Solve an equation in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve this equation (both numerically and literally) only in the positive reals $\mathbb{R}^+$?

```
Solve[x == (v0 - (A CD t v0^2 ρ)/(4m)) Cos[θ] t, t]
```

And for example, is there a way to have an output like this :

```
52.0756
```

and not like this :

```
{{t -> -52.3918}, {t -> 52.0756}}
```

?

Comment: You can add a condition like `sol=Solve[{...,t>0},t]`; then you can do `sol[[All,1,2]]`.

Comment: For the first leg of your question, there is a good tutorial in the documentation of Mathematica entitled "equations and inequalities over domains". `Reduce` is what you probably want to try out. As for the solutions being given as rules, the documentation of `Solve` has every possible way to extract those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `ReplaceAll` (i.e. `/.`) and `Select`

```
Select[x /. Solve[x^2 - 1 == 0, x], Positive]
```

gives

> {1}

It is a list (`List`) not a single number. You might not know how many positive solutions exist:

```
Select[x /. NSolve[(x - 1) (x + 3) (x - 3) == 0, x], Positive]
```

> {1., 3.}

**Edit:**

Using `Part` or its short-hand notation `[[]]` you can select parts from the list:

```
Part[{1}, 1]
```

> 1

```
{1}[[1]]
```

> 1

```
Part[{1.,3.},2]
```

>   3.

Comment: Isn't possible remove from the output also the braces, right?

Comment: @FormlessCloud Yes you can if you have one result, however how would you return 2 numbers without braces ?

Comment: I have selected the positive reals appositely for have one result, but I don't know how to remove the braces from the output. I don't want the braces because I want use the result as a value for a command and if I keep the braces the result can't be taken as numerical value.

Comment: @FormlessCloud I updated the answer to show how to get rid of the braces.

Answer (score 14):

The first items of **More Information** in the documentation of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en) says :

- The system `expr` in `Solve[expr,vars]` can be any logical combination of:

  ```
  lhs == rhs               equations 
  lhs != rhs               inequations 
  lhs > rhs or lhs >= rhs  inequalities 
  expr ∈ dom               domain specifications 
  ForAll[x,cond,expr]      universal quantifiers 
  Exists[x,cond,expr]      existential quantifiers
  ```
- `Solve[{ expr1, expr2,...},vars]` is equivalent to  `Solve[ expr1 && expr2 &&...,vars]`.

Every `expri` can be  an equation, inequality as well as an expression tests like e.g. `Positive` or `Negative` etc., thus we can do simply e.g. `Solve[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x]`, but to get only the list of solutions (without `Rule`s ) there are at least two ways:

- using `ReplaceAll` (shorthand `/.`) (mentioned by Markus Roellig) with the condition `x > 0`  :

  ```
  x/.Solve[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x]
  ```

  > ```
  > {1, 2, 3}
  > ```
- using `Part` (shorthand `[[]]`) with e.g. `x > 0` or with an expression test like `Positive`, `NonNegative` etc.:

  ```
  Solve[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && Positive[x], x][[All, 1, 2]]
  ```

  > ```
  >  {1, 2, 3}
  > ```

The above ways can be mixed, e.g. : `x /. Solve[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x][[3]]`. 
We needn't point out the domain `Reals` since the condition `x > 0` implies that `x` is a positive and real  number. The same concerns `Reduce`, i.e. use it like e.g.

```
Reduce[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x][[All, 2]]
```

Comment: Not valid in Mathematica 6, I think?

Comment: @SanjayManohar What do you mean? `Solve` has been updated since the _version 6_ nevertheless all this syntax was valid, or perhaps you missed something?

Comment: on Mathematica 6.0: `Solve[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x]` ==> "`Solve::eqf : x>0 is not a well-formed equation`"

Comment: @SanjayManohar In _version 6_ one could do it with `Reduce` e.g. `Reduce[-36 + 49 x^2 - 14 x^4 + x^6 == 0 && x > 0, x]`, `Solve` has worked this way since _version 8_, before equations had to be  given in the form `lhs == rhs` only, although e.g. `ForAll`, `Exists` had been introduced in _version 5_.