# Assign the result of Solve in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

I want to assign the results of a Solve command in a list. For example
Solve[-((287 s^3)/50) == 0, s] returns {{s -> 0}, {s -> 0}, {s -> 0}}
I want it to return {0,0,0}.
Can this be done automatically and not manually?
Thank you very much

Comment: Lookup `Part` in the docs.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate...  perhaps not exact, but maybe:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121

Comment: Also off-site:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1616091/618728 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8355218/618728

Comment: Here is another related question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
s = Solve[-((287 s^3)/50) == 0, s][[All,1,2]]
```

To get

```
s = {0,0,0}
```

Comment: ...or `s /. Solve[-((287 s^3)/50) == 0, s]`

Comment: `Solve[-((287 s^3)/50) == 0, s][[All, 1, 2]]` more than `Solve[-((287 s^3)/50) == 0, s][[All,2]]`

Comment: You are rigth. Corrected

Comment: Ok thank you very much, you are very quick with your answers and helpful. I have been trying to find it for some time but couldn't, now i'll go check out more details in the documents about 'part'. Thanks a lot