# Forcing FindRoot to return only real solutions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, complex

`FindRoot` documentation reports that if the equation and the initial point are reals, the solutions are searched in the real domain.
However, in the following case I get a complex solution

```
FindRoot[eq, {h, 1.7}]
   {h -> -0.990042 - 0.689686 I}
```

Same for

```
Assuming[Reals, FindRoot[eq, {h, 1.7}]]
```

Where `eq` is the following. What can I do to force *Mathematica* to return only real solutions?

```
eq = 0.2888960456513873` \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + (0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 2.2076945564517114` h \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 6.735521430523215` h^2 \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 10.54153050379155` h^3 \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 8.93280406600778` h^4 \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 3.8752891330788843` h^5 \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 0.666148416209407` h^6 \[Sqrt](0.4149486782073932` + 
(0.5637605604986459` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + (0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) + 0.4167441738314279` \[Sqrt](0.4756674436221575` + 
(0.9900423417575865` + 
        h)^2) \[Sqrt](1 - (0.4444444444444444` 
(-0.022551321792606827` + (0.5637605604986459` + 
             h)^2)^2)/(0.4149486782073932` + (0.5637605604986459` + 
           h)^2))
```

Comment: `NSolve[ eq == 0, h, Reals]` yields `{}` i.e. there are no real solutions.

Comment: Same if you `Plot[Re[eq], {h, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: Thank you.
Actually the equation I am using is much longer, it has reals solutions, which I obtained by picking up only the real solutions. To speed up my algorithm I wanted to force findroot itself to return only real solutions

Comment: With the complete equation I am using, NSolve does not return

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera You could restrict the region to find solutions, e.g. `NSolve[ eq == 0&& -5 < h < 5, h, Reals]`.

Comment: It is possible than during the process of solving the equation `FindRoot` substitutes a `h` value which results in a complex `eq`.  This then throws off the method the real line and it'll give you complex solutions as well.

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera Can you provide an example with real roots ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will be more convenient to define the function `eq` this way :

```
eq[h_] := the formula
```

### Real solutions

For a general technique of using `FindRoot` the way you would like I recommend to read this post : [First positive root](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579). However in order to demonstrate how it works for real numbers we should have a different equation since this one has no real solutions :

```
NSolve[ eq[h] == 0, h, Reals]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Sometimes it is reasonable to restrict the search for roots to a special region, e.g. if we add an inequality  `0 < h < 3` then we don't have to specify the domain `Reals` because the system understands that `h` must be real  :

```
NSolve[ eq[h] == 0 && 0 < h < 3, h ]
```

General remarks on using `NSolve` you could find here : [Solve an equation in R+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)
since they are valid for `Solve` as well as for `NSolve`.

For the function `f` we can find a global minimum of the real part :

```
nmin = { h /. #[[2]], #[[1]]}& @ NMinimize[ Re @ eq[h], h]
```

> ```
> {-1.83596, 0.100607}
> ```

For an idea what we can expect let's plot the real and imaginary parts of `f` :

```
Plot[{Re @ eq[h], Im @ eq[h]}, {h, -3, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {-1, 4}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[nmin]},
      PlotLegends -> {Placed["Expressions", {Left, Center}]}]
```

[image]

Even though `eq` has no real roots we can see that one can expect real solutions e.g. for `eq[h] - 3/2` near `h == -2` and `h == 0`, using `FindRoot` with appropriate starting points we find :

```
FindRoot[ eq[h] - 3/2, #]& /@ {{h, -2}, {h, 0}}
```

> ```
>  {{h -> -2.15793}, {h -> 0.14209}}
> ```

For deeper understandig  of the behavior of the `eq` function we should take a look at the complex plane.

### Complex solutions

The complex roots can be rewritten as pairs of real numbers :

```
pts = {Re @ #, Im @ #}& /@ (h /. NSolve[ eq[h] == 0, h])
```

> ```
> {{-1.86925, 0.135055}, {-1.86925, -0.135055}, {-1.08654, 0.84989},
>  {-1.08654, -0.84989}, {-0.990042, 0.689686}, {-0.990042, -0.689686},
>  {-0.0268207, 0.391104}, {-0.0268207, -0.391104}}
> ```

Let's visualize the function `eq` in the complex plane :

```
GraphicsRow[ 
    Table[ Show[ ContourPlot @@@ {
      { g[eq[x + I y]], {x, -2.5, 0.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
        PlotLabel -> Style[ g[HoldForm @ eq[x + I y]], Blue, 25],
        ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Epilog -> { Darker @ Green, PointSize[0.03], 
                                                      Point[pts] } },
      { Re @ eq[x + I y] == 0, {x, -2.5, 0.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
        ContourStyle -> {Red, Thick}},
      { Im @ eq[x + I y] == 0, {x, -2.5, 0.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
        MaxRecursion -> 3, ContourStyle -> {Cyan, Thick}}}],

             {g, {Re, Im}} ] ]
```

[image]

The green points denote the complex roots, you can see that there are no real roots. The red lines are solutions to `Re[ eq[h] ] == 0` while the cyan lines denote solutions to  `Im[ eq[h] ] == 0`. One can see a that there are some branch cuts on the plots, i.e. the definition of the function `eq` is reliable only if we use it in appropriate regions in the complex plane.

Comment: very nice plots!

Comment: @chris Thanks. Sometimes plots are crucial to understand what lies beneath.