# How can I obtain the complex root of an equation with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I want to obtain the complex roots of some equations that are similar,but each of them has a different condition. this difference is the value of `α` in these equations. When I try to obtain the complex roots, just the real part is close to correct value, but the imaginary part is identical for all of the equations, and an error message was returned every time. What is the reason for this?

The coding has many special characters and fancy formatting, making it hard to post my code here, so I have posted images. The images show the main equation with `α = .1` and the results for `α = .1` `α = .2` and `α = .3`, respectively, and the error message I got.

Here are the images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here is the code:

```
 Subscript[j, ν, 1][s_] = s*(SphericalBesselJ[0, s]) - 1*(SphericalBesselJ[1, s])
 Subscript[j, 1][s_] = SphericalBesselJ[1, s]
 Subscript[n, ν, 1][s_] = s*(SphericalBesselY[0, s]) - 1*(BesselY[1, s])
 Subscript[n, 1][s_] = SphericalBesselY[1, s]
 Subscript[h, 1][s_] = SphericalBesselJ[1, s] + I*(SphericalBesselY[1, s])
 Subscript[h, ν, 1][s_] = 
   s*(SphericalBesselJ[0, s] + I*(SphericalBesselY[0, s])) - 
   1*(SphericalBesselJ[1, s] + I*(SphericalBesselY[1, s]))
 α = .1
 β = .95
 Subscript[u, B][w_] = 
   .10114688*Sqrt[5.59` + 0.031098192`/((3.30216`- 0.000049206` I) - w)]
 Subscript[u, C][w_] = .10114688* w Sqrt[3.7` - 81/((0. + 0.01728` I) w + w^2)]
 Subscript[u, A][w_] = .10114688*Sqrt[1.777]*w
 Subscript[u, D][w_] = .10114688*w

 FindRoot[Det[{
   {Subscript[j, 1][α Subscript[u, D][w]], -Subscript[j, 1][α Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    -Subscript[n, 1][α Subscript[u, C][w]], 0, 0, 0}, 
   {((Subscript[u, C][w])^2)*Subscript[j, ν, 1][α Subscript[u, D][w]], 
    -((Subscript[u, D][w])^2)*Subscript[j, ν, 1][α Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    -((Subscript[u, D][w])^2)*Subscript[n, ν, 1][α Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, Subscript[j, 1][β Subscript[u, C][w]], Subscript[n, 1][β Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    -Subscript[j, 1][β Subscript[u, B][w]], -Subscript[n, 1][β Subscript[u, B][w]], 0}, 
   {0, ((Subscript[u, B][w])^2)*Subscript[j, ν, 1][β Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    ((Subscript[u, B][w])^2)*Subscript[n, ν, 1][β Subscript[u, C][w]], 
    -((Subscript[u, C][w])^2)*Subscript[j, ν, 1][β Subscript[u, B][w]], 
    -((Subscript[u, C][w])^2)*Subscript[n, ν, 1][β Subscript[u, B][w]], 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, Subscript[j, 1][Subscript[u, B][w]], 
    Subscript[n, 1][Subscript[u, B][w]], -Subscript[h, 1][Subscript[u, A][w]]}, 
   {0, 0, 0, ((Subscript[u, A][w])^2)*Subscript[j, ν, 1][Subscript[u, B][w]], 
    ((Subscript[u, A][w])^2)*Subscript[n, ν, 1][Subscript[u, B][w]], 
    -((Subscript[u, B][w])^2)*Subscript[h, ν, 1][Subscript[u, A][w]]}
  }] == 0, {w, 4.6}]
```

Comment: Try to examine a method exploiting `RootIntervals`, e.g. see this answer [First positive root](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579), it works also for complex variables.  This [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/forcing-findroot-to-return-only-real-solutions/18297#18297) might be helpful as well.

Comment: @morteza - even after your revision I can't read anything

Comment: I am tring to embed the codes but how can I embed the codes with their basic form in mathematica?

Comment: @eldo-I do not this diagram, if you apply roots = FindRoot[det, {w, #}] & /@ Range[-5.1, 5.1, 1]; the error message is staied.

Comment: When I try to find the root of the equation the answer is the one that is accompany with an error .I'm sure this is not the right answer because I know that the real part of the root is about 4.4 and in this answer is about 4.6. I am looking for a way to give the correct answer to the equation and then use it for my next works diagrams,... . If the starting point is lower than 4.1, we give the right answer and no error message but in this new start point the solution is relevant to other problem that I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

This is how far I came with your problem:

```
det = Det[{ ... }] == 0;

roots = FindRoot[det, {w, #}] & /@ Range[-5.1, 5.1, 1];

points = Point /@ 
  Union@Round[Flatten[roots /. Rule[_, Complex[a_, _]] :> {a, 0}, 1],0.0001]
```

> {Point[{-4.679, 0.}], Point[{-3.0736, 0.}], Point[{3.0729, 0.}], 
>    Point[{4.6788, 0.}]}

```
fun = First@det;

Plot[{Re@fun, Im@fun}, {w, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Epilog -> {Green, PointSize@0.02, points}]
```

[image]