# Solving Complex Equation Over Reals

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I want to solve the equation $\frac{abi}{a+bi}=4-2i$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. I know from hand-solving the answer is $a=5$, $b=-10$. How do I get *Mathematica* to tell me this?

I tried:

```
Solve[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I, {a, b}]
```

but this returns

```
{{b -> -(((2 + 4 I) a)/((-4 + 2 I) + a))}}.
```

I tried

```
Solve[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I, {a, b},Reals]
```

but this returns

```
Solve[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I, {a, b},Reals].
```

Is there a simple way of getting *Mathematica* to solve this, without knowing lots of special *Mathematica* commands? In searching out the answer on this site, I see workarounds that a newbie to *MMA* would never think of themselves, nor understand what they are doing that gives the right answer.

Comment: `Solve[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I && (a | b) ∈ Reals, {a, b}]`. This might be slightly related: [Solve an equation in R+](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188).

Comment: That works - thanks! What does (a | b) mean? Specifically, what's the pipe?

Comment: See `Alternatives`. You can use `Solve[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I && a ∈ Reals && 
  b ∈ Reals, {a, b}]` as well.

Comment: @Artes If you make your comment an answer I'd mark it as my favorite. The one given currently is essentially the same, but yours is more succinct and, imo, more intuitive.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but I think you could accept the answer given by Alexei since that one is quite appropriate. On the other hand you might find helpful more detailed discussion of `Reduce` and `Solve`: [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Reduce[a b I/(a + b I) == 4 - 2 I && a ∈ Reals && 
  b ∈ Reals]

(* b == -10 && a == 5 *)
```