# Why doesn't Roots work on a certain quartic polynomial equation?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, polynomials

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

In everything that follows I am using `Roots` to get the solutions to the equations.

I start off with this equation: 
$$ \frac{A}{3}x^4 - x^2 + 2ax - b^2 = 0$$ 
Now `Roots` gives me back $4$ complicated looking solutions to this.

Now if one stares at the solutions it appears that if one tunes to $a =b = \sqrt{\frac{3}{16 A}}$ then these 4 solutions collapse to $3$ namely, $ x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{A}}, -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{A}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{6}{A} }$

**however**

- when I from the beginning itself set $a = b = \sqrt{\frac{3}{16 A}}$ and run `Roots` on the equation the system just hangs!
- And of these $3$ solutions the "$\pm$" *doesn't* seem to satisfy the original equation. (with $a = b = \sqrt{\frac{3}{16 A}}$)

Can someone kindly explain what is happening?

Comment: Including the actual code you use in the question eliminates ambiguities.

Comment: It's a bug. Will file a report and investigate. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Exposition of the problem

`Roots` works well on the following equation (obviously it yields **generic formulae** and it doesn't deal with exceptional cases e.g. **when `A == 0` qurtics expressions are not valid**):

```
eq = A/3 x^4 - x^2 + 2 a x - b^2 == 0;
```

while in a special case of `eq` it fails (however in *Mathematica 9* the system **doesn't hang**) returning the following warning:

```
eq1 = eq /. {a -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)], b -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)]}
```

> ```
> -(3/(16 A)) + 1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1/A] x - x^2 + (A x^4)/3 == 0
> ```

```
Roots[ eq1, x]
```

> ```
> $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >> 
>
> Hold[ Roots[ -9 Sqrt[1/A] + 24 Sqrt[3] x - (48 x^2)/Sqrt[1/A] 
>              + (16 x^4)/(1/A)^(3/2) == 0, x]]
> ```

### Remedy

We can rewrite  `eq1` with:

```
Simplify[ eq1, A > 0 && x != 0]
```

> ```
> 24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[A] x + 16 A^2 x^4 == 9 + 48 A x^2
> ```

now `Roots` **works well**:

```
TraditionalForm @ Roots[ Simplify[ eq1, A > 0 && x != 0], x]
```

[image]

### Explanation

In the latter case (of `eq1`) the system **automatically** rewrites the equation to another form not purely polynomial (the constants involving a square root of `A` are treated like another variables) involving more solutions than ordinary polynomials.

### Discussion and subtleties

In general solving symbolically equations we encounter various problems related to basic concepts, space of variables, range of interesting solutions, constants, etc. 
Here we tackle with an issue of constants and when `A` is not restrected somehow `Roots` is not able to provide a satisfactory solution, even tough with a more general case it works reasonably (yielding generically correct answers). There are another functions like `Reduce` which can provide full information on the solution space.

Whenever one doesn't know why an equation cannot be solved with one method it is reasonable to try another ways, and since symbolic capabilities for solving equations are related behind the scenes one should try more reliable aproaches. `Roots` basically works on **polynomial equations**, while `Reduce` and `Solve` can tackle with transcendental ones, moreover `Reduce` is more capable to provide symbolic results (an example: [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952)). These issues were discussed more extensively in another post [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).

Let's provide results from more reliable functions. `Solve` was updated in version *8* and now it can tackle with much larger class of equations, however it 
fails:

```
Solve[ eq1, x]
```

> ```
> { ToRules[ Hold[ Roots[-9 Sqrt[1/A] + 24 Sqrt[3] x - (48 x^2)/Sqrt[1/A]
>                           + (16 x^4)/(1/A)^(3/2) == 0, x]]]}
> ```

on the other hand Reduce` shows what happens behind:

```
Reduce[ eq1, x]
```

> ```
>  Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) 
> { 0 == (-1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A], 0 == (-1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A],
>   0 == (-1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A], 0==(-1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A],
>   0 == (1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A], 0 == (1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A],
>   0 == (1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A], 0 == (1-Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[A]}. 
>
> A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts 
> of Mathematica functions. >>
> ```

and then it yields also solutions  in terms of

> ```
> Root[ 9/A^2 - 24 (1/A)^(3/2) Reduce`CADAlgVar[1] #1 + (48 #1^2)/A - 16 #1^4 &, k]
> ```

This information clarifies what the problem is, namely the equation is transformed to another form which is not a pure polynomial one and such an equation has more solutions than an ordinary polynomial, see e.g.

```
Simplify[ eq1]
```

> ```
> 8 x (3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1/A] - 6 x + 2 A x^3) == 9/A
> ```

More on this issue one can find in another [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129) which I linked above. But for a quick reference one should realize that `Solve` in similar problems yields this warning:

> ```
> Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition A ∈ Reals, 
>  the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; 
>  use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
> ```

This obviously happens when we deal with symbolic equations, however choosing specific 
numeric coefficients it works well.  Ahother way is to supplement the equation `eq1` by a condition e.g. `A > 0`, however `Roots` is **not capable to deal with boolean formulae**, nonetheless it can be done with `Solve` or `Reduce` (see e.g. this answer [Solve an equation in R+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)), e.g.:

```
Solve[ eq1 && A > 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{ x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1/A], A > 0]}, 
>  { x -> ConditionalExpression[ Root[9 - 72 A #1^2 + 16 A^2 #1^4 &, 1], A > 0]}, 
>  { x -> ConditionalExpression[Root[9 - 72 A #1^2 + 16 A^2 #1^4 &, 3], A > 0]}}
> ```

In conclusion we can say that the underlying issue is not a desirable feature of the system(it works on more general ones while fails on special cases), however `Roots` is not intended to tackle with exceptional cases. Moreover we can expect that similar issues will be present in next versions, since there can always appear some problems related to appropriate restricting constants  in algebraic equations.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Clear[A, a, b, x];
eq1 = A/3*x^4 - x^2 + 2*a*x - b^2 == 0;
```

Now, as you propose:

```
    eq2 = Simplify[eq1 /. {a -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)], b -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)]}, 
  A > 0]

(*   24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[A] x + 16 A^2 x^4 == 9 + 48 A x^2  *)
```

With this one finds:

```
    Solve[eq2, x]

(*  {{x -> Sqrt[3]/(2 Sqrt[A])}, {x -> Sqrt[3]/(
   2 Sqrt[A])}, {x -> (-Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[6])/(
   2 Sqrt[A])}, {x -> (-Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6])/(2 Sqrt[A])}}  *)
```

Exactly as you expect to obtain. So, what?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. (1) When I set the values to those special points and evaluated "roots" on it the system hung up. Did it happen for you too? (2) And aren't you also seeing that those last 2 of your roots are not a solution of the equation?

Comment: @user6818 1) No the solution has been returned immediately. 2) `eq2 /. x -> (-Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6])/(2 Sqrt[A])`returns `True` as well as `eq2 /. x -> (-Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[6])/(2 Sqrt[A])`. Thus, no, I do not see that.