# Reduce return a strange result for solving a equation with radical

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.3**

---

```
Reduce[1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]), x]
```

the output is unreadable and include the symbol `` Reduce`CADAlgVar[1] ``.

Comment: Same in all versions between 9-10.2.  But this is not a question.  If you think you found a bug, please contact Wolfram Support.  Posting here won't ensure that they will even see it.

Comment: Confirm unexpected output on Win7-32/MMA 10.1. Given the community confirmations I've added the bugs tag.

Comment: Possibly related? [Why doesn't Roots work on a certain quartic polynomial equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51598/27951)

Comment: The same bug even in Mathematica 7.0.1 on Win7x64.

Answer (score 7):

Restrict the domain to `Reals`

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
eqn = 1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]);

sol = Reduce[eqn, x, Reals] // ToRules
```

> {x -> Root[1 - 10*#1^2 - 4*#1^3 + 
>                #1^4 + 20*#1^5 + 6*#1^6 - 
>                10*#1^8 - 4*#1^9 + #1^12 & , 
>            4]^2}

```
eqn /. sol // FullSimplify
```

> True

```
sol // N
```

> {x -> 0.800116}

```
eqn /. (sol // N)
```

> True

**EDIT:** Update for v11.3

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

eqn = 1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]);

sol1 = Reduce[1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]), x] // ToRules

(* {x -> Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, -2 + #2^2 &, -1 + 5 #3 - 2 #1 #2 #3 + 2 #1 #3^2 - 
      2 #2 #3^2 + #3^3 &}, {2, 2, 1}]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol1 // RootReduce

(* True *)
```

Restricting the domain to [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html) gives the same result as with the earlier version

```
sol2 = Reduce[1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]), x, Reals] // ToRules

(* {x -> Root[
   1 - 10 #1^2 - 4 #1^3 + #1^4 + 20 #1^5 + 6 #1^6 - 10 #1^8 - 
     4 #1^9 + #1^12 &, 4]^2} *)
```

The different [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects are equivalent

```
(x /. sol1) == (x /. sol2) // RootReduce

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in MMA 11.3.

```
ToRadicals[Reduce[1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]), x]]
```

> x == 2/3 (Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]) + 1/(
>     3 (2/(27 - 22 Sqrt[2] + 18 Sqrt[3] + 
>        3 Sqrt[3 (27 - 44 Sqrt[2] + 36 Sqrt[3])]))^(1/3)) + 
>     1/3 (5 - 2 Sqrt[6]) (2/(
>       27 - 22 Sqrt[2] + 18 Sqrt[3] + 
>        3 Sqrt[3 (27 - 44 Sqrt[2] + 36 Sqrt[3])]))^(1/3)