# Selecting results according to the constraint

Tags: equation-solving

It is very likely that this question is a duplicate, but unfortunately I have not found the solution.

Among the results of a [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), I would like to apply for the Variable `x` a `Real` and `Positive` value.

My attempt:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sol = Solve[x^4 - x^2 - 5 == 0, x]
SelectFirst[sol, Real]
SelectFirst[sol, {Real, Positive}]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}-1\right)}\right\},\left\{x\to i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}-1\right)}\right\},\left\{x\to -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+1\right)}\right\},\left\{x\to \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+1\right)}\right\}\right\}$
>
> $---$
>
> $---$

I made a small variation of the above code by adding `/. Rule -> Set`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sol = Solve[x^4 - x^2 - 5 == 0, x] /. Rule -> Set
x
SelectFirst[sol, Real]
SelectFirst[sol, {Real, Positive}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}-1\right)} \\
>  i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}-1\right)} \\
>  -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+1\right)} \\
>  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+1\right)} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+1\right)}$
>
> $---$
>
> $---$

I was able to apply the desired value to the Variable `x`, but I could not do anything with the Variable `sol`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not include the constraint in the `Solve`?: `sol = Solve[x^4 - x^2 - 5 == 0 && x > 0, x]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve an equation in $\mathbb{R}^+$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr). It would be reasonable to examine also this post: [First positive root](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579)

Comment: or use `Select[sol, Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 &]`

Comment: @egwenesedai I think `x>0` already implies `Element[x, Reals]`, wich already evaluates to `True|False` so no need for `Equal` (`==`) either.

Comment: @rhermans yes, you are right that `==` is not necessary; `Element[x, Reals]` is to safeguard against the warning `invalid comparison with [complex number] attempted.`.

Comment: just an aside: first need to flatten `sol` with `sol = Solve[x^4 - x^2 - 5 == 0, x] /. Rule -> Set // Flatten`, then use `Select[sol, Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 &]` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are days when you have forgotten everything ...

```
Reduce[{x^4 - x^2 - 5 == 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]
```

[image]