# Solve with > instead of ==

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a complicated equation with the sign > instead of ==. However, mathematica Solve function is not defined for >. Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Code example:

```
Solve[a^2-b^2 > 0,a]
```

Expected Result:

```
a > b and a > -b.
```

Comment: `Reduce[a^2 - b^2 > 0, a, Reals]`

Comment: Thanks alot. It works for me

Comment: Also, applying `PowerExpand` to the result will replace `Sqrt[b^2]` with `b`, so if you know that $b \geq 0$, you can make the result look even nicer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - what you say is true; however, some users are likely to misuse `PowerExpand`.  I would recommend using `Simplify` so that the assumptions are explicit, e.g., `Simplify[#, b >= 0] &`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  Yes, that's probably a better idea.

Comment: This answer should clarify your problem [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve),  perhaps this might be helpful as well  [Solve an equation in R+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)

Comment: This will reduce the inequality to linear relations, if that is what you want: `Reduce[Reduce[a^2 - b^2 > 0, b, Reals], a, Reals]`.  So will this: `CylindricalDecomposition[a^2 - b^2 > 0, {b, a}]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that Solve can not deal with inequalities.

This problem has not one or a finite number of solutions. The solution are separated region in the {a,b}-plane.

```
Reduce[a^2 - b^2 > 0, a, Reals]

a < -Sqrt[b^2] || a > Sqrt[b^2]
```

Even better seems:

```
RegionPlot[a^2 - b^2 > 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}]
```

[image: RegionPlot of the inequality]

This is a correct input for the question:

```
Solve[a^2 - b^2 > 0, {a, b}, Reals]
```

[image: warning]

```
{{}}
```

The Mathematica documentation for this result for the built-in [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is

"Solve uses {} to represent the empty solution or no solution:"

What does that mean?

Wolfram Inc gives the example

```
Solve[x == x, x]
```

This is a tautology. The intend is to state this is a correct input, but it has no finite set of solutions. Only complete `Reals` is the solution.

Same is true for Your input. The same is programmed in Mathematica if the input is valid but overdetermined or already the solution.

The most appropriate input is

```
Reduce[a^2 - b^2 > 0, {a,b}, Reals]

(a < 0 && -Sqrt[a^2] < b < Sqrt[a^2]) || (a > 0 && -Sqrt[a^2] < b < 
    Sqrt[a^2])
```

This is the symbolic representation of the RegionPlot visualization.

[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

is specialized for such problems. It. contains `Solve` and many more algorithms. Reduce in a generalization of Solve for more complex infinite solutions and inequalities. The proper question would be, why is not `Solve` redundant to `Reduce`. `Solve` may rise less costs in use.

There is indeed a workaround for the question to get meaningful results with Solve.

```
sol = Solve[x^2 - y^2 == 0, {x, y}]

Plot[Evaluate[Re[y /. sol]], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Plot of the boundaries of the above Region]

Mathematicians are usually both interested in the region and the boundary of the region.

The same result comes with

```
sol = Solve[x^2 - y^2 == 0, {x, y}, Reals]

{{y -> -Sqrt[x^2]}, {y -> Sqrt[x^2]}}
```

Both are different for Mathematica.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[y /. sol]], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Plot of the boundary of the above region over Reals]

```
sol = Solve[x^2 - y^2 > 0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

[image: Warning for the corresponding inequality using Solve]

An example for finishing this:

```
sol = Solve[x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

[image: warning]
[image: warning]

Solve seems not to work with Assumptions like Simplify does. It knows logical connectives.

For deeper insight than Mathematica documentation does:

[What is the difference between `Reduce` and `Solve`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve)

Nice is

```
Solve[a*x == 0, x]
(* Out: {{x -> 0}} *)

Reduce[a*x == 0, x]
(* Out: a == 0 || x == 0 *)
```

So the implicit assumption already made if using `Solve` are much wider than using `Reduce` for two independent variables. That should answer the question and give advise how to solve the question.